# Laravel. Объединение двух приложениий

Tags: laravel

Имеется сайт на laravel.
Появилась нужда в форуме. Есть идеальное готовое решение форума на laravel которое мне подходит.

Будет ли правильным, если я просто помещу в public/forum - ещё одно приложение laravel форума целиком и буду использовать 2 БД?

Или же это процедура выполняется как то по другому?

Comment: добавить миграции, модели, контроллеры, роуты (и тд) к вашему имеющемуся приложению врятле будет сложно)

Comment: Я так боялась этого комментария) Тоесть закидывать вьюхи и миграции, роуты и ТД в уже существующий проект?

Comment: С умом конечно) + не забудьте проверить зависимости и тд)

Answer (score 0):

В лучшем случае если у тебя 2 разных приложения на laravel, то сделай на суб домене forum.domain.com если же ты хочешь чтоб пользователи были одинаковыми и на сайте и на форуме используй одну модель User.

В идеале напиши свой форум под сайт. И все будет синхронизировано =)

Comment: В идеале понятно) Но вдруг бы были какие то готовые варианты для решения подобного вопроса) Ведь в моем случае уже всё написано)

Comment: @Moon Готовых решений точно нет. Laravel же фреймворк всего лишь, тут уже надо руками делать что-то)

Comment: Бесспорно, но несоизмеримо "чуть-чуть подправить" и "написать с нуля")